# Android : How to fix the error about setting.adzcore.com

Tags: android

My android app has the error like following.

W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "setting.adzcore.com": No address associated with hostname
W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:156)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
        at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:41)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:178)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:144)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:86)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:176)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:411)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:542)
        at it.partytrack.sdk.compress.f.a(Unknown Source:167)
        at it.partytrack.sdk.compress.f.a(Unknown Source:14)
        at it.partytrack.sdk.compress.k.run(Unknown Source:93)
    Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
        at libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:74)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.android_getaddrinfo(BlockGuardOs.java:200)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:74)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:135)
        ... 17 more

Comment: If the request to setting.adzcore.com is removed, it'll be fixed.
But I can't remove this request.
Please help me.

Comment: `setting.adzcore.com` is invalid url . use correct url

Answer (score 0):

Replace `setting.adzcore.com` with `https://setting.adzcore.com`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But I can't find where there is the url.
Do you know which file I should replace in.

Comment: Are you using any library that would be making a call to `setting.adzcore.com` ?

Comment: I'm using some libraries, but I don't know which library calls to setting.adzcore.com.